# Add substrings in column values in Pandas if pattern mattches

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, mapping

I have two dataframes, with cell names and some values for that cells, like this:
cell_df:

```
cell_name    cell_values
abc1b        (h 1, a 2, a4)
adc2g        (h 2, a 4, a5)
daf1g        (h 3, a 7, a2)
adg2d        (h 1, a 4, a4)
```

And the other one:

record_df:

```
record_id record_values
1        start abc1b 1 2 , daf1g  3 5
2        start adc2g 6 7 , adg2d  6 5
3        start abc1b 10 13 , adc2g  2 3
```

What I need is to put cell_values before each comma, for that cell_name appear before that same comma and string "from" before first number, string "to" between two numbers

Desired output:

```
record_id record_values
1        start abc1b from 1 to 2 (h 1, a 2, a4), daf1g from 3 to 5 (h 3, a 7, a2)
2        start adc2g from 6 to 7 (h 2, a 4, a5), adg2d from 6 to 5 (h 1, a 4, a4)
3        start abc1b from 10 to 13 (h 1, a 2, a4), adc2g from 2 to 3 (h 1, a 4, a4)
```

I think I got that with my code below, but it takes a huge amount of time to proceed, a few minutes, but dataframe has just 80 rows.

```
for cn, cv in cell_df[['cell_name', 'cell_values']].values:
    record_df['record_values'] = record_df['record_values'].apply(lambda x: (re.sub(r"%s(\s+)(\d+)\s+(\d+)" % cn, r"%s from \1 to \2 %s" % (cn, cv), x)))
```

So, the question is: is there any way to speed that up? Maybe a whole different approach?

I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

### With Python 3.6 f-strings

Create a dictionary from `cell_df`

```
m = dict(cell_df.values)

def fmt(rec):
    pre, txt = rec.split(maxsplit=1)
    return pre + ' ' + ', '.join(
        f'{a} from {b} to {c} {m[a]}'
        for a, b, c in map(str.split, map(str.strip, txt.split(',')))
    )

record_df.record_values.apply(fmt)

0    start abc1b from 1 to 2 (h 1, a 2, a4), daf1g ...
1    start adc2g from 6 to 7 (h 2, a 4, a5), adg2d ...
2    start abc1b from 10 to 13 (h 1, a 2, a4), adc2...
Name: record_values, dtype: object
```

- `pre, txt = rec.split(maxsplit=1)` lops off that initial `start` bit and puts it into the `pre` name.  This leaves `txt` with the triples we want to reformat.
- Then I want to `split(',')` the value in `txt`
- For each element in that `split` I want to `strip` off excess spaces
- Then I want to `split` those results by spaces
- This should result in a `list` of `list`s or `Iterable` of `Iterable`s where each `Iterable` should be of length `3`
- I can unpack those `3` values into `a`, `b`, and `c`
- Then I reformat those with an f-string or `str.format` function
- Put everything back together with a `', '.join`

  ---

### Pre-Python 3.6

```
m = dict(cell_df.values)

def fmt(rec):
    pre, txt = rec.split(None, 1)
    return pre + ' ' + ', '.join(
        '{} from {} to {} {}'.format(a, b, c, m[a])
        for a, b, c in map(str.split, map(str.strip, txt.split(',')))
    )

record_df.record_values.apply(fmt)
```

---

### Tailored for OP

```
m = dict(cell_df.values)

def fmt(rec):
    pre, txt = rec.split(None, 1)
    return pre + ' ' + ', '.join(
        '{} from {} to {} {}'.format(a, b, c, m[a])
        for a, b, c in map(str.split, map(str.strip, map(str, txt.split(','))))
    )

record_df.record_values.apply(fmt)
```

Comment: Invalid syntax at the end of this part : f'{a} from {b} to {c} {m[a]}', I can't figure it out where exactly.

Comment: Now I got an error for line : pre, txt = rec.split(maxsplit=1), TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments. Btw, thank you very much for helping. :)

Comment: TypeError: descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'

Comment: I added an additional `map` to convert stuff to strings.  Not sure if that'll work.

Comment: Unfortunately won't. ValueError: too many values to unpack
To be honest I'm not getting what you have done here (in fmt function) so I can't make any minor changes without you, to make this works.

Comment: Yeah, that's problematic.  I'll explain some.

Comment: I've added some explanation.  Hope it works out.  I'll be away for a bit.